# Sequelize: overlapping - Checking if any value in array matches any value in the passed array

Tags: sql, node.js, database, postgresql, sequelize.js

Using sequelize to check if the the db input property, which is array, has a given item.
Have a Postgres database with data *Events*.
Want to get one *Event* that will have any of these *weekDays*.
Type of *weekDays* is ARRAY(integer).

```
Events.findOne({
  where: {
    weekDays: {
      $contains: [2, 3],
    },
  },
});
```

Tried to do with $contains, $any, or $like $any but all the time got the same error message.

> TypeError: values.map is not a function

Sincerely thanks

Comment: did you use `$in` clause? And I will recommend `$like` clause...

Comment: @AshishChoudhary tried with $in and $like as well, same error

Comment: Ok... use `findAll` instead of `findOne`

Comment: Again same error

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You are looking for overlapping values. Any value in you `weekDays` array that matches any values in your passed in array.

As such, you can use the PG specific `Sequelize.Op.overlap` operator:

[See documentation here](https://sequelize.org/docs/v6/core-concepts/model-querying-basics/#postgres-only-range-operators)

Can then be used like

```
Events.findOne({
  where: {
    weekDays: {
      [Sequelize.Op.overlap]: [2, 3],
    },
  },
});
```